# How to create one farm solution with 2 web service reference url

Tags: web-services, farm-solution

We are using SP2010 enterprise on-premise. In a farm solution there is a web references to Excel Service. The Web Reference URL is:
http://production/_vti_bin/excelservice.asmx

The solution is working as expected in production but not work in development because in development the correct URL is:
http://development/_vti_bin/excelservice.asmx

How can we create single farm solution (and generate single WSP file) which works in both farm?